# How can I set the dateCreated attribute on an EntryModel?

Tags: plugin-development, entrymodel

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$entry = EntryModel::populateModel(array(
    'dateCreated' => DateTimeHelper::formatTimeForDb($someTimeStamp),
    'sectionId' => 1
    'typeId' => 1
));

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated` and `uid` columns are more internal Craft auditing columns that Craft manages for every row in every table.

Maybe what you're looking for is the `postDate` column for entries, which you can set a custom value to.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Is postDate the date you see in the CP when you're creating an entry? We basically want to set that to a date in the past when creating entries via our plugin.

Comment: I believe so, yeah.